# I am trying to when i open the popup view then my webview is paused

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

```
func AboutYoga() {

    let width = mywebview.frame.width
    let height = mywebview.frame.height
    let frame = 0
    mywebview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    mywebview.scrollView.bounces=false
    let videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/36Q3V7WY3F0?rel=0&amp;controls=1&amp&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;playsinline=1"
    let htmlUrl = "<html><body><iframe width=\(width) height=\(height) src=\(videoUrl) allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"

    mywebview.loadHTMLString(htmlUrl, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
}
```

I am using above function for playing video in uiwebview

In this image popup is open but previous video is playing.please tell me solution

Comment: can you explain your problem in detail?

Comment: @Prajaktapatil: Your screenshot is not visible properly, you can take screenshot of simulator directly by pressing Command(⌘) + S together.

Comment: when i am open popup that time my previous video is playing  but i want pause the video

Comment: here I am using UIwebview

Comment: @ArpitDongre I m change my Image here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these line of codes when you show & hide the Pop Up message respectively:

**To Pause:**

```
mywebview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.querySelector('video').pause()")
```

**To Play:**

```
mywebview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.querySelector('video').play()")
```

Comment: @ArapitDongre: I am using above line but it showing error .so this line is supported mywebview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.querySelector('video').pause()") but code not working

Comment: Try "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("player.pauseVideo()")